# Image height returns 0 on appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm appending divs, and I need to get the image height en width. I need to add css to the MB-Container class, according to the height/width of the image

> example: portrait -> container width 100%, landscape ->
>     'self-align':'flex-end'

```
$('.MB-Container').append('' +
  '<div class="Cover-Item">' +
    '<img src="' + cover + '" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>' +
    '</div>' +
  '</div>');
```

However when trying to get the height and width of the image, I'm getting zero for height:

```
var itemWidth = $('#item1 .Cover-Item img').width();
var itemHeight = $('#item1 .Cover-item img').height();
```

How can I add a onload function in the append to check for the image width/height?

I've tried:

```
$(document).on("load",".Cover-Item img", function() {

}).each(function() {
   if(this.complete || /*for IE 10-*/ $(this).height() > 0)
   console.log($(this).load());
     $(this).load();
});
```

But this only fires once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

The actual `onload` function is blank in your example.  This might work:

```
$(document).on("load",".Cover-Item img", function() {
   if(this.complete || /*for IE 10-*/ $(this).height() > 0)
   console.log($(this).height());
});
```

Comment: Haha.. Oops. I did add it, but it only fires once. While I'm having more images.

Comment: When is the command as a whole run?  `.on()` only applies to elements that exist at the time it is first run.  See peeebeee's link.